# How do I avoid the jerking when I do an Infinite Horizontal Scroll?

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

Platform: iOS 10+

I'm able to make a crude infinite scrolling loop via watching WWDC11.

  However I can't figure out the algorithm to smooth out the jerking effect.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Here's the collection view, to be scrolled horizontally:

[image]

Here's the UICollectionView where I'm attempting to create an infinite horizontal scroll effect (allowing for the initial scroll to trigger it):

```
@implementation PhotoCollectionView

- (void)recenterIfNecessary {
    CGPoint currentOffset = self.contentOffset;
    CGFloat contentWidth = self.contentSize.width;
    CGFloat centerOffsetX = (contentWidth - self.bounds.size.width) / 2.0;
    CGFloat distanceFromCenter = fabs(currentOffset.x - centerOffsetX);

    if (contentWidth > 0 && (distanceFromCenter > (contentWidth / 2.5))) {
        self.contentOffset = CGPointMake(centerOffsetX, currentOffset.y);
        // Move content by the same amount so it appears to stay still.
        // Note: Need to determine correct algorithm.
        //       Ran out-of-time on this one.
    }
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self recenterIfNecessary];
}

@end
```

How do I provide a SMOOTH scroll vs the cell-replenish jerk?

...I want to also use this within Swift 4+ as well as Objective-C.

Comment: Does it have to be based on `UICollectionView`?

Comment: Yes.   I assume it would be easier if it was based on UITableView or purely UIScrollView.  But my whole design is based on UICollectionView.

Comment: Have you made the `UICollectionView` so that it fills photos to the right? Do you want "true" endless scrolling, that can be scrolled in both directions, filling up from start when reaching end? Or are you after a regular collection view that is dynamically loaded as the user scrolls?

Comment: Yes.  Infinite scrolling left <--> right.  However, it would be nice to know the best way to dynamically lazy load as the user scrolls.   I believe can can figure that out via delegation.

Comment: Have you made the `UICollectionView` to fill cells left and right instead of top & bottom?

Comment: I am asking because I have made several "endless" scrolling views, but none of them based on `UICollectionView`, although I have used `UICollectionView` also, for other purposes.

Comment: ...that's the problem.  I've been requested to perform an endless scroll.   I got it to 'work', but with obvious jerking as the photos reposition themselves.

Comment: Are you sure the jerkiness is from repositioning and not from slow loading times of the photos?

Comment: I'm not doing a lazy load.   I've merely loaded the entire load and would like to do an infinite load of the existing data (i.e., cycle around to the first image...etc.)